# Find what will be the working X years from a given date

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Suppose that I buy a at the money European Call  on the EuroSTOXX 5O on the 1990/01/10 with maturity of 9 years. I would like to know what will be the maturity date.
Any idea?

I can start with the `quantmod` package:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("^STOXX50E", from = "1990-01-01")
maturity <- 9
dates <- index(STOXX50E)
```

The problem is that I cannot use

```
dates[1] + maturity*365
```

or

```
dates[1] + maturity*252
```

to find the maturity date because the number of working days varies across years.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: 365 is a sub-optimal representation of a year because there are technically 365.25 days in a year (leap year)

Comment: @Statwonk Actually there are about 365.24 days in the average year because years divisible by 100 are not leap years unless they are also divisible by 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the `lubridate` package for this problem.

```
require(quantmod)
require(lubridate)
getSymbols("^STOXX50E", from = "1990-01-01")
maturity <- 9 # years

dates <- as.POSIXct(as.character(index(STOXX50E)), tz = "UTC") # needs to be in POSIXct format to work with lubridate, I believe.

maturity_dates <- dates + years(maturity) 

head(as.data.frame(list(dates = dates, 
                        maturity_dates = maturity_dates)))

  dates          maturity.dates
1 1990-01-01     1999-01-01
2 1990-01-02     1999-01-02
3 1990-01-03     1999-01-03
4 1990-01-04     1999-01-04
5 1990-01-05     1999-01-05
6 1990-01-08     1999-01-08
```

Comment: The problem is that: package ‘lubricate’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)

Comment: Well, upgrade R and your packages then. See e.g. [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/09/r-3-0-2-and-rstudio-0-9-8-are-released/).

Comment: @marino89, it is `lubridate` with a `d` like `Dumbo`.

Comment: I fixed the `Date` to `POSIXct` conversion by first converting the date to character and then `POSIXct`.  Anyone have issues with that hack?